# WCF in VB.NET - Error on Function trying to return Array

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have set a WCF in VB.NET and I'm trying to make a function return an array.
This is not working out right! I tried a lot of things and googled it a lot.

So the error is:

[image]

My Function in the WCF:

```
    Public Function GetCL_Contacts(ByVal cl_ID As Integer) As String() Implements SQLOperator.GetCL_Contacts
    Dim Contacts() As String
    Contacts = {}
    Try
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = SQLConString
        SQLCon.Open()

        SQLCMD = New SqlCommand("Select Nome from dbo.cl_contact Where cl_ID=" & cl_ID & " ORDER BY ID ASC;", SQLCon)
        SQLDataReader = SQLCMD.ExecuteReader()

        Dim I As Integer = 0
        While SQLDataReader.Read
            Contacts(I) = SQLDataReader("Nome")
            I = I + 1
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro: " & Environment.NewLine & ex.ToString)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Close()
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try

    Return Contacts
End Function
```

How I'm trying to use the function:

```
    'Load Contacts
    Dim Contacts() As String
    Contacts = {}
    Contacts = Service.GetCL_Contacts(clBox.SelectedIndex + 1)
    For Each contact As String In Contacts
        BoxCl_Contacts.Items.Add(contact)
    Next
```

How I tried to solve this (and completely failed):

- I tied to declare the contacts like this: Dim Contacts(100) As String
- Another declare: Dim Contacts(0 To 100) As String

None of the above worked!

Comment: How many rows are returned by your query?  As you are finding, arrays are a poor choice here.  Have you considered using a `List(Of String)` instead?  The `Dim Contacts(100) As String` syntax is OK to create an array with 101 items, but what if you have more than 101 rows returned?

Comment: You are right. An array is not the best choise I will try to use the List (Of String).

Comment: It did solve everything. Thanks for the little tip!

Comment: @Mark `but what if you have more than 101 rows returned`, **ReDim Preserve Contacts(how many?)** would work... Although not the best solution, but is very doable... Not only would it keep the array, it would then resize just fine.

Comment: @Codexer Sure, but you would be `ReDim`ming every time around the loop - i.e. `ReDim Preserve Contacts(Contacts.Length)`.  While it works, it involves copying the array every time.  May as well let `List<T>` handle that for you, since it's a bit smarter about how the internal array is handled, and you can always set the initial capacity.  You could call `ToArray()` on the list at the end if you really want an array.